log4j 1.x EOL vulnerability on Alfresco Community 5.2.0?
We noticed that Alfresco Community 5.2.0 version comes with Log4j 1.x ,we know that log4j 1.x is already at End of life please confirm when these will be removed from product?
We tried removing file and restarted services but it didn't worked.

You can not just remove a dependency from Alfresco and expect that the product will still work. Starting from ACS 7.4, log4jv2 will be the library used for logging capabilities, so you should upgrade your Alfresco version to get supported dependencies.
s. Alfresco Community Edition 7.4 Release Notes
